# How to get resource jar path in runnable jar program?

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, resources

I've made a runnable jar that has another jar within it as a resource. During the execution of the program depending on what the user does, I need to call the resource as another java program eg. java -jar m.jar. So what I'm asking is how do I get the path of the resource jar in the jar file so i can run it like this Runtime.getRuntime().exec(...); Or is there any other way to do this? I've used getClass.getResource().getPath() but I just keep getting the jar name, not the absolute path. I forgot how to get the path but I do remember that the path has '!' after the jar eg, /module.jar!/module2.jar or something like that. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: i think you cannot access a jar from another jar for that you will have to place the resource jar at the root with the main jar file and then access it

Answer (score 0):

A jar is compressed zip file, **not** a normal directory that you can just do `java -jar MainApp.jar/m.jar`

To fix that you would need to put the `m.jar` file **outside** the main jar file, and then you can execute it normally.

Answer (score 0):

Just put the first jar in the classpath and call the first class from within the second class as you would instantiate any other class.
For example, if the original call was java -cp ./m.jar Main

And the second class was CallerClass, then in CallerClass just do a 
Main main = Main();